# Is there way to use Only a part of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

simply i want to separate some part of MyCSS.css and Bootstrap4.css

because Bootstrap is breaking My CSS but i wanna use some part of Bootstrap4.

I know how to get part Bootstrap4 CSS code but searching one by one is so tire.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCSS.css">

<body>
<!-- where i want to use only MyCSS.css -->
<div>
    ...
</div>

<!-- where i want to use only Bootstrap4.css -->
<div>
    ...
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you can't specific the css file only to div rather than the other. css file will be used in all the html file. instead, you can override css properties from bootstrap that you don't want in Mycss.css

Comment: other thing would be useful: you bootstrap itself has precompiled css files instead of the whole css file: like grid.css see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/contents/#css-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize and download only the required bootstrap components from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

Answer (score 2):

Download Bootstrap Sass and remove unwanted styles and compile only what u want